# Get first and last month in pandas dataframe where a specific value occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
datetime    Year    cal val
1/1/2000    2000    1   0.23
1/2/2000    2000    1   0.34
2/3/2000    2000    1   0.45
4/4/2000    2000    2   0.56
4/5/2000    2000    2   0.67
4/6/2000    2000    2   0.78
5/7/2000    2000    3   0.89
7/8/2000    2000    3   1
7/9/2000    2000    3   1.11
```

The datatime column represents the dataframe index.

I would like to find the month with the last cal == 1 value (this would be `february`). Similarly, I want to find the month with the first cal == 3 value (this would be `may` in this example.). right now, I can do subset:

```
df[df.cal == 1]
```

but not sure how to proceed from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` to find the subset that matches your condition, then access the first element of the resulting index with `[0]` and the last element with `[-1]`.  Use `.month` to get the integer of the relevant month.

"I would like to find the month with the last cal == 1 value (this would be february)."

```
>>> df.loc[df.cal == 1].index[-1].month
2
```

"Similarly, I want to find the month with the first cal == 3 value (this would be may in this example.). "

```
>>> df.loc[df.cal == 3].index[0].month
5
```